Parsing Open Files Stuck in Infinite Loop for C/C++ Tools (IntelliSense)
I am experiencing difficulties with the C/C++ IntelliSense extension on VsCode and have tried virtually every solution on the internet to no avail. In particular, I am stuck on an infinite "infinite parsing loop," which renders all features of C/C++ IntelliSense disabled, including but not limited to coloring text, hovering for definitions (which causes infinite loading), etc.
I am connected to a Linux machine via Remote - SSH.

OS and Version: Apple M1 Pro Mac OS Sonoma 14.4.1
VS Code Version: 1.88
C/C++ Extension Version: Most recent
OS of Remote Machine (SSH): Fedora Linux 38 (Server Edition)

Inside my .vscode directory I have two files: c_cpp_properties.json and settings.json which is blank (I have tried adding many configs to this file to no avail). My c_cpp_properties.json file is populated with the following code:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/lib64/ccache/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

I have attempted many solutions, including removing all other extensions to isolate the bug. I have also deleted the .vscode and .vscode-server directories and .cache etc. Upon opening VSCode again, .vscode-server folder is automatically generated, which is expected. Meanwhile, no IntelliSense features are available.
Here are the Log Diagnostics:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~**Log Diagnostics**~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

-------- Diagnostics - 4/25/2024, 6:12:59 PM
Version: 1.19.9
Current Configuration:
{
    "name": "Linux",
    "includePath": [
        "/home/accts/ckk25/**"
    ],
    "defines": [],
    "compilerPath": "/usr/lib64/ccache/clang",
    "cStandard": "c17",
    "cppStandard": "c++17",
    "intelliSenseMode": "linux-clang-x64",
    "compilerPathIsExplicit": true,
    "cStandardIsExplicit": true,
    "cppStandardIsExplicit": true,
    "intelliSenseModeIsExplicit": true,
    "compilerPathInCppPropertiesJson": "/usr/lib64/ccache/clang",
    "mergeConfigurations": false,
    "browse": {
        "path": [
            "/home/accts/ckk25/**",
            "${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
    }
}
cpptools version (native): 1.19.9.0
Translation Unit Mappings:
[ /home/accts/ckk25/cs223Main/hw5/Island.cpp - source TU]:
[ /home/accts/ckk25/cs223Main/hw7/main.cpp - source TU]:
Translation Unit Configurations:
[ /home/accts/ckk25/cs223Main/hw5/Island.cpp ]:
    Process ID: 708586
    Memory Usage: 79 MB
    Compiler Path: /usr/lib64/ccache/clang
    Includes:
        /usr/include/c++/13
        /usr/include/c++/13/x86_64-redhat-linux
        /usr/include/c++/13/backward
        /usr/lib64/clang/16/include
        /usr/local/include
        /usr/include
    Standard Version: c++17
    IntelliSense Mode: linux-clang-x64
    Other Flags:
        --clang
        --clang_version=160006
[ /home/accts/ckk25/cs223Main/hw7/main.cpp ]:
    Process ID: 708552
    Memory Usage: 104 MB
    Compiler Path: /usr/lib64/ccache/clang
    Includes:
        /usr/include/c++/13
        /usr/include/c++/13/x86_64-redhat-linux
        /usr/include/c++/13/backward
        /usr/lib64/clang/16/include
        /usr/local/include
        /usr/include
    Standard Version: c++17
    IntelliSense Mode: linux-clang-x64
    Other Flags:
        --clang
        --clang_version=160006
Total Memory Usage: 183 MB

------- Workspace parsing diagnostics -------
Number of files discovered (not excluded): 40666


EDIT—I believe I have a partial solution. By changing the line "includePath": ["${workspaceFolder}/**"], to "includePath": [ "${workspaceFolder}/*"], in c_cpp_properties.json, I have eliminated the infinite parsing error. However, the single * is non-recursive includes and non-recursive browse path, which is undesirable as sub-directories will not get parsed. I am investigating other work-arounds currently.

** shouln't be necessary. Surely you aren't passing every individual subdirectory in an -I flag to your compiler?
